# bridging header does not exist

Tags: objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I am trying to use AKPickerView pod written in Objective C in a Swift, but I keep getting this error 
 Bridging header '/Users/bogdanbarbulescu/Desktop/Inapk/Inapk/Pods-Inapk-umbrella.h' does not exist .

I have done the following settings:
    1. Under Build Settings
    Defines Module    YES

```
Under Swift Compiler
Code Generation
Objective-C Bridging Header    - set to path- 
/Users/bogdanbarbulescu/Desktop/Inapk/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-       Inapk/Pods-Inapk-umbrella.h

In Pods-Inapk-umbrella.h I input this statement: #import "AKPickerView.h"  [Image showing error][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcEY7.png
```

Please let me know if you know how can I fix this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you do the following.
Instead of putting something inside the pods, create a bridging header in your project group.

Easiest way I found, is to simply create a new cocoaTouch class right clicking on your project and selecting new file. 
[image: new class]

and select objective-c for the language.

This will ask you for your permission to create a bridging header file.
In that, import the module you want to use #import "AKPickerView.h"

Comment: Thanks Jason, It worked but now I get another error when I build the project "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -600.)"
I created a bridiging header file then I imported my module #import <AKPickerView/AKPickerView.h>, then I clicked on my workspace, build settings, Objective-c Bridging Header and I dragged and dropped the bridging header to get its path.

Comment: Below is my code

`import UIKit`
`import AKPickerView`

`class ViewController: UIViewController, AKPickerViewDelegate,` `AKPickerViewDataSource {`

    `var myArray = ["one","two","three"]`
    `@IBOutlet var pickerView: AKPickerView!`
    
    `override func viewDidLoad() {`
        `super.viewDidLoad()`
        `// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.`
        
        `self.pickerView = AKPickerView(frame: CGRect.zero)`
        `self.pickerView.delegate = self`
        `self.pickerView.dataSource = self`
    `}`

Comment: `func numberOfItemsInPickerView(pickerView: AKPickerView!) -> UInt {`

 `return UInt(self.myArray.count)`
   ` }`
    
    
   ` func pickerView(pickerView: AKPickerView!, titleForItem item: Int) ->String!{`
        `return self.myArray[item]     }`
   
`}`